# Prepostions after Adjectives

Tags: grammar

Maybe this question sounds dumb but as a non-English native speaker, what confuses me the most is the use of prepositions after adjectives.
So, I guess, I can use any preposition after any adjective flexibly depends on what i want to say.
I mean, it's not like I can use only some restricted prepositions after an adjective except for phrase verbs, right?

Comment: This is too vague a question.   Do you have any examples of what you're unsure about?  Have you tried to find information on it elsewhere?

Comment: @rjpond I heard there are 100+ prepositions in English so if i want to use the adjective "adamant" am i able to use every single preposition after the adjective? like "adamant for, adamant over, adamant in etc". will that phrase still be grammatically correct?

Comment: No, you can't use every single preposition. See https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/beginner-to-pre-intermediate/adjectives-and-prepositions Dictionaries can also help: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/angry  You can be adamant over or adamant on or adamant concerning something - although "adamant about" is by far the most common.  The others can sound odd and may have more restricted application.

Comment: "Adamant" most naturally selects an "about" PP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, you are completely able to use prepositions after adjectives.

Firstly, we can look at the (simple) definitions of a preposition and an adjective and how they interrelate.

- A preposition is a linking word.
- An adjective describes/modify's a noun or a pronoun.

Example 1 - (Preposition 'at'): She's amazing *at* the piano.

Example 2 - (Preposition 'about'): I'm angry *about* the decision.

Example 3 - (Preposition 'of'): **You should be proud *of* your progress with prepositions** ;).

You do have to be selective, but prepositions may be used after adjectives.

Hope this helps - Jeko.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if i say I'm angry on/over/for the decision instead of "about" Is that still a thing? do they sound idiomatic?

Comment: _Angry over_ is possible, but not _on_ or _for_.

Comment: You definitely can't be angry "on" anything,.  You can be "angry about", "angry over", "angry with", or "angry at" a decision (and you can be "angry at" or "angry with" a person).

Comment: @Kate Bunting, rjpond thank you so much!! it means a lot :)